# What is Font-Awesome internaly?

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

Font-Awesome provides us with lots of great and useful icons. I suppose that those icons are encoded using Unicode. I am pretty sure that UTF-8 does not contain them, neither does either known charachter table. So how is Font-Awesome presented internally, why does it appear correctly? Is it just an ordinary font but with no letters, and only with special icons, listed in the ttf file? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want to know the internals, why not look through https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it just an ordinary font but with no letters, and only with special icons, listed in the ttf file?

Jep, that's about how it works.

If you look at the FA.css file you'll notice that the classes you are using to get the icon basically all look something like:

```
.fa-ellipsis-h:before {
    content:"\f141"
}
```

So if you make a div that has `style="font-family:FontAwesome"` you can basically type `&#xf141;` and will get the same icon as with `<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>`